# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all' with Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup, find-all-references

I have tried this code I found, however it gives me the error message of AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'
I am not familiar with Beautifulsoup and dont know how to fix this. tried to find a solution where I ignore the tabpane part, but could not figure it out.
Do you have any sugggestion?

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd # pip install pandas
import requests # pip install requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup # pip install beautifulsoup4

headers = {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:87.0) 
Gecko/20100101 Firefox/87.0',
}
url = 'https://www.marketwatch.com/tools/earningscalendar'
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

tabpane = soup.find('div', 'tabpane')
earning_tables = tabpane.find_all('div', {'id': True})

dfs = {}
current_datetime = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%m-%d-%y %H_%M_%S')
xlsxwriter = pd.ExcelWriter('Earning Calendar 
({0}).xlsx'.format(current_datetime), index=False)

for earning_table in earning_tables:
    if not 'Sorry, this date currently does not have any earnings 
announcements scheduled' in earning_table.text:
        earning_date = earning_table['id'].replace('page', '')
        earning_date = earning_date[:3] + '_' + earning_date[3:]
        print(earning_date)
        dfs[earning_date] = pd.read_html(str(earning_table.table))[0]
        dfs[earning_date].to_excel(xlsxwriter, sheet_name=earning_date, 
index=False)

xlsxwriter.save()
print('earning tables Excel file exported')
```

Comment: `tabpane` is `None` and all the code after it is irrelevant.

Comment: What is `response.content`? Can you create a string with the minimal content that still doesn't work as expected? Requests is probably irrelevant also. See how to create a [mcve] and edit the question.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion. it should be something like; HEADERS: Company Name, Symbol, Fiscal Quarter, EPS Forecast, EPS Actual, Surprise.

Answer (score 1):

To grap all tables in page:

```
tables = pd.read_html("https://www.marketwatch.com/tools/earnings-calendar")
```

Just look at the first:

```
print(tables[0].head())
```

If you are sure all tables have same columns, you can concat them to have only one dataframe:

```
df = pd.concat(pd.read_html("https://www.marketwatch.com/tools/earnings-calendar"))
```

Comment: I see that he is trying to parse the html to pandas and save it through `pd.ExcelWriter`. Otherwise, the `pd.read_html` can be also useful if the  correct soup of the table is passed as `str`.

Comment: apologies, I was hasty.

Comment: Hi Nameless. Thank you for the tip. I checked this one before, but then I miss the date of relevance, when actually the Earnings are reported. With your suggested solution I am just pulling out the data wherever it is not NULL. Any idea how to parse it per day?

Comment: hi! also, it does not really go for future tables. if you click on the link, you will see future tables are not even recognized. can you please help? thanks